# Android library from maven ExceptionInInitializerError (IntelliJ IDEA 12)

Tags: android, maven, exception, languagetool

I try to use LanguageTool library http://www.languagetool.org/java-api/ in my android app,

```
    try
    {
       JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(new Polish());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {}
```

but I'm getting an error. I added maven library using Modules-->Dependencies-->Add-->library -->from maven.

Everything works, when I test it as console application.

```
 11-07 19:54:35.071: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.example.orto_test.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:35)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.languagetool.JLanguageTool.getBuildDate(JLanguageTool.java:93)
    at org.languagetool.JLanguageTool.<clinit>(JLanguageTool.java:77)
    ... 15 more
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of LanguageTool are you using? Is there really ```catch (IOException e) {}``` in your code or is that just here in your question? There shouldn't be, as it hides errors.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://languagetool-user-forum.2306527.n4.nabble.com/ClassDefNotFoundError-org-languagetool-language-AmericanEnglish-td4641443.html Languagtool 2.2 can be used on Android successfully. You might want to contact the languagetool-user-forum if you have trouble in getting things to work.